# Express adds slash at the end of url weirdly

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm using Node.js and Express framework for developing a website. I faced weird misbehaviour with a url. When i click to related link url, url becomes "localhost:3000/images/" - a slash is added at the end as you can see. But when i change all 'images' to 'img' or else url becomes "localhost:3000/img" no slash added. Why router behaves like that?  Codes written below. (I'm using Jade template Engine)

```
//bar.jade    
li.nav-item
      a.nav-link(href='images')
        i.icon-camera
        |  Images

//end of bar.jade


//images.js (router)
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('images', { title: 'Express'});
});

module.exports = router;
//end of router .js



//app.js
var images =require('./routes/images');
........
........
app.use('/images',images);
//end of app.js
```

Comment: Try running your browser in incognito/private mode to see if it still happens. Also check your browser's dev tools to see what's going on exactly.

Comment: It behaves same way in private mode and in other browsers too. I checked html and it looks normal. I didn't use browser's dev tools much. What do you think should i check?

Comment: Specifically the initial server response when loading `/images` (whether or not the server returns a 301/302 status).

Comment: I checked via Webstorm's console. It shows 'GET /images 303'  'GET /images/ 304' then all assets load with 304 response

Comment: Yeah, I figured out the issue :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think I know what's going on: you're also using the `express.static()` middleware, and in your public directory you have a directory called `images/`.

This middleware will generate redirects ending with a slash when you try to request a URL that matches a public directory (even when that directory is empty or matches another route).

To disable this behaviour, set the [`redirect` option](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) to `false`.

Comment: You are right. I deleted the images folder and it didn't redirect. I'm impressed.

Comment: @Emre goes to show that you provide _all_ info when asking questions ;D

Comment: Oh my god. This is it. I have been looking for this answer for god knows how long. You are a life saver. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

By default in express router “/foo” and “/foo/” are treated the same by the router. You can disable this behavior with `strict: true` option.

[Express.Router documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router)

```
var router = express.Router({strict: true});
```

Comment: They are treated the same, but from the question it sounds like there's a redirect from `/images` to `/images/`, which isn't something that Express does.

Comment: Yes, @robertklep is right. I tried different words at the same code but only 'images' word, Express redirects.