# How can I avoid auto adding slash to an express route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect, routes

I have already searched for a solution, but unfortunately none of them worked. Maybe you can help me.

I am programming a plugin based webserver with Node.JS and Express. The main webserver code looks like this:

In this part all plugins are initialized and all routes of the main webserver. Here is the compilation of the plugins and the main webserver

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const settings = require('../settings/settings');

// Events
const events = require('./functions/events/events');

// Webserver
const app = express();


// Ordnerpfade definieren
const pluginsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'plugins');
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, 'public');
const routesPath = path.join(__dirname, 'routes');
const viewsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'views');


// ETA RENDER ENGINE
const eta = require('eta');
eta.configure({
  views: viewsPath,
  useWith: true,
  autoEscape: true,
  cache: false
});
app.set('view engine', 'eta');

// Öffentliche Ressourcen des Webservers
app.use(express.static(publicPath, {
  redirect: false
}));

// Plugins einbinden
global.plugins = {};
global.plugins.pluginData = {};
var pluginsActive = {};   //aktive Plugins
var pluginSettings = [];  // Settings einzelner Plugins
var pluginAssets = [];    // Assets einzelner Plugins

var pluginData = [];

function filterDirectories(dir) {
  return fs.lstatSync(path.join(pluginsPath, dir)).isDirectory();
}

function getFilesInDirRec(fileExtension, pluginPublicFolder, dirPath, ignoredDirs, pluginName) {
  let files = [];
  fs.readdirSync(dirPath).forEach((file) => {
    const filePath = path.join(dirPath, file);
    const fileStat = fs.statSync(filePath);
    if (fileStat.isDirectory()) {
      if (!ignoredDirs.includes(file)) {
        const subDirFiles = getFilesInDirRec(
          fileExtension,
          pluginPublicFolder,
          filePath,
          ignoredDirs,
          pluginName
        );
        files = files.concat(subDirFiles);
      }
    } else if (file.endsWith(`.${fileExtension}`)) {
      var assetPath = path.join("/", pluginName, path.relative(pluginPublicFolder, filePath));
      files.push(assetPath);
    }
  });
  return files;
}

fs.readdirSync(pluginsPath).filter(filterDirectories).forEach(pluginName => {
  pluginData[pluginName] = {};

  // Pfad zum Plugin
  const pluginPath = path.join(pluginsPath, pluginName);

  // Öffentliche Ressourcen des Plugins
  const pluginPublicPath = path.join(pluginPath, 'public');
  if (fs.existsSync(pluginPublicPath)) {
    app.use(`/${pluginName}`, express.static(pluginPublicPath, {
      redirect: false
    }));
  }
  
  // Routen des Plugins
  const pluginRoutesPath = path.join(pluginPath, 'routes');
  if (fs.existsSync(pluginRoutesPath)) {
    fs.readdirSync(pluginRoutesPath).forEach(routeName => {
      routeName = routeName.split('.')[0];
      if(routeName === "index"){ routeName = ""}
      const router = require(path.join(pluginRoutesPath, routeName));
      app.use(path.join('/', pluginName, routeName), router);
    });
  }
  
  // Views des Plugins
  const pluginViewsPath = path.join(pluginPath, 'views');
  if (fs.existsSync(pluginViewsPath)) {
    app.set(`views`, [pluginViewsPath, viewsPath]);
  }

  // JS und CSS Dateien des Plugins auslesen
  const ignoredDirNames = ["helper"];
  const pluginJSfiles = getFilesInDirRec(   "js", pluginPublicPath, path.join(pluginPublicPath,   'js'), ignoredDirNames, pluginName);
  const pluginCSSfiles = getFilesInDirRec(  "css", pluginPublicPath, path.join(pluginPublicPath,  'css'), ignoredDirNames, pluginName);
                                            // Dateiendung                                        // Unterordner in "plugin/public"
  pluginData[pluginName].assets = {};                                          
  pluginData[pluginName].assets.css = pluginCSSfiles;
  pluginData[pluginName].assets.js = pluginJSfiles;

  // Settings des Plugins
  const pluginsSettingsPath = path.join(pluginPath, 'settings');
  if (fs.existsSync(pluginsSettingsPath)) {
    const thisPluginSettings = require(`${pluginsSettingsPath}/pluginSettings`);
    pluginData[pluginName].settings = thisPluginSettings;
  }
  
  // Alle aktivierten Plugins global speichern
  pluginsActive[pluginName] = true;
  
});

global.plugins.active = pluginsActive;
global.plugins.pluginData = pluginData;


// Middleware
const middleware = require('./middleware/middleware');

// Routen des Webservers hinzufügen
fs.readdirSync(routesPath).forEach(routeName => {
  routeName = routeName.split('.')[0];
  if(routeName === "index"){ routeName = ""}
  const router = require(path.join(routesPath, routeName));
  app.use(`/${routeName}`, router);
});



// Handle 404
app.use(function(req, res) {
  if (res.headersSent) {
      return;
  }
  res.status(404);
  res.render("404", {});
});


const start = function() {
  // Webserver starten
  app.listen(settings.server.port, () => {
    console.log('Webserver gestartet unter Port: ' + settings.server.port);
  });
};


module.exports = {
  start
};
```

Here is the route `index` and `test` of the web server.

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router({ strict: true });
const eta = require('eta');
const path = require('path');


const viewsPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'views');
eta.configure({
  views: viewsPath
});

const middleware = require('../middleware/middleware');

// Router-Instanz in Middleware-Funktion umwandeln
const pluginRouter = express();
pluginRouter.use(router);



// Eine Route-Instanz definieren
router.get('/', [middleware.plugins.getActivePlugins, middleware.metaData.getMetaDataSkeleton], async (req, res, next) => {
  
  var templateData = {};
  templateData = req.middlewareData.templateData;
  
  templateData.metaData.title = templateData.metaData.app.name + " - Startseite";
  
  templateData.metaData.customMetaTags.push({
    proberty: "test",
    oder: true,
    but: "no"
  });
  
  console.log(templateData);
  eta.renderFile('index', templateData)
  .then(html => {
    res.send(html);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  });

});

// Eine Route-Instanz definieren
router.get('/test', [middleware.plugins.getActivePlugins, middleware.metaData.getMetaDataSkeleton], async (req, res, next) => {
  
  var templateData = {};
  templateData = req.middlewareData.templateData;
  
  templateData.metaData.title = templateData.metaData.app.name + " - Startseite";
  
  templateData.metaData.customMetaTags.push({
    proberty: "test",
    oder: true,
    but: "no"
  });
  
  console.log(templateData);
  eta.renderFile('index', templateData)
  .then(html => {
    res.send(html);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  });

});




module.exports = pluginRouter;
```

When I call a route there, no matter if `https://example.cc` or `https://example.cc/test` - the link is not changed and stays as it is.

However, when I call a route of a plugin, eg https://example.cc/blog or https://example.cc/tags a slash `/` is always automatically added to the end of the link results in https://example.cc/blog/ and https://example.cc/tags/ The developer console in Google Chrome says that there is a 301 redirect to the page with the `/` at the end.

Here is the code of a route of the plugin:

```js
const path = require("path");
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const eta = require('eta');

const viewsPath = path.join(__dirname, "..", 'views');
eta.configure({
  views: viewsPath
});


// Registrieren des Event-Listeners
const events = require('../../../functions/events/events');


// Plugin Router Initialisieren
const pluginRouter = express();
pluginRouter.use(router);


// GLOBAL MIDDLEWARE
const middleware = require('./../../../middleware/middleware');

// LOCAL MIDDLEWARE
const pluginMiddleware = require('./../middleware/pluginMiddleware');
const testMiddleware = pluginMiddleware.test;

// Eine Route-Instanz definieren
router.get('/', [middleware.plugins.getActivePlugins, middleware.metaData.getMetaDataSkeleton, testMiddleware], (req, res, next) => {
  var templateData = {};
  templateData = req.middlewareData.templateData;

  templateData.metaData.title = templateData.metaData.app.name + " - Blog";

  console.log(templateData);
  // Auslösen eines Events
  events.emitter.emit('getBlogIndex', {
    eventData: "is-test"
  });

  // Rendern einer Datei
  eta.renderFile(path.join(viewsPath, 'index'), templateData)
  .then(html => {
    res.send(html);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  });

});




module.exports = pluginRouter;
```

---

No matter what I tried, nothing worked. It always made a 301 redirect in the plugins to the same page but with the extra `/`.

I tried the following:

I read this has something to do with the static files. Each plugin comes with its own static folder. The directory is on the same level as the directory for the plugin routes.
https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html
[Express adds slash at the end of url weirdly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34391440/express-adds-slash-at-the-end-of-url-weirdly)

So I tried to set the option `redirect` to false. Which unfortunately did not bring any success.

For plugin:

```js
// Öffentliche Ressourcen des Plugins
  const pluginPublicPath = path.join(pluginPath, 'public');
  if (fs.existsSync(pluginPublicPath)) {
    app.use(`/${pluginName}`, express.static(pluginPublicPath, {
      redirect: false
    }));
  }
```

For main webserver

```js
// Öffentliche Ressourcen des Webservers
app.use(express.static(publicPath, {
  redirect: false
}));
```

Then I also tried setting the `strict` option in the plugins router. This did not work either.

[Express adds slash at the end of url weirdly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34391440/express-adds-slash-at-the-end-of-url-weirdly)

In each route

```js
const router = express.Router({ strict: true });
```

I also tried a combination of both. Nothing causes the route to stop doing 301 forwarding.

In addition, I still tried this option:
[Trailing slash gets appended to url in express server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124892/trailing-slash-gets-appended-to-url-in-express-server)

on main webserver init

```js
app.enable('strict routing');
```

Which unfortunately didn`t do anything either. I don't know what else to look for. Can you help me? Because I come here unfortunately not further. Would be very happy! Kind regards.

I am using **express ^4.18.2**

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of rest, I revisited the problem and was able to solve it. It was more by chance but I saw in the Chrome developer console that the page is loaded from the disk cache. And that was the whole problem why my attempts failed.

[image: chrome development console]

So I repeated my failed attempts and the solution was quite simple. It was just this line here that I added to the plugin routes:

```
const router = express.Router({ strict: true });
```

I started the incognito mode to have a pristine environment. And look, everything worked as it should.

Now I can access each route via
`http://example.cc/blog` and `http://example.cc/blog/` with no differences.

I would not have expected that operations called on the server would also be cached in some way on the client. It's just the link here but that was enough to keep me busy for a while.

Cheers.